# CSWP - Display List of List and Libraries

Tags: content-search-web-part

I would like to use the out of the box Content Search WebPart to show a list of Document Libraries available in the current site, like:

*Document Library 01

Document Library 02

Document Library 03*
...

More specifically, the list should show libraries using a custom content type.

Please help me getting this done.

Comment: Do you want that to be done only using content search web part ? or you are open for other options ?

Comment: This query will return all list of ContentClass containing Document Library
path:{\SiteCollection.URL}/
(contentclass:STS_List_DocumentLibrary)

Comment: @eVT It did not work, not sure if I am doing any mistake.

Comment: Are you getting any results in CSWP? Did you configure SharePoint Search service application? Did you create content sources in a SharePoint Search service application?  Content Search WebPart rely on SSA (Search service application).

Comment: First thing I am using Office 365 SharePoint, so service application is configured and should be working fine. Second, the query does not result any items, please check this screenshot: https://goo.gl/gxZn23